# Removing “and” from “…takes small weapon and inserts into his jacket.”

Tags: sentence-construction, conjunctions

> Mike takes small weapon and inserts into his jacket.

I want to make the above sentence into one single sentence without the conjunction. I guess I'm not aware of some word. That's why I'm finding it difficult. It’s not about grammar, its about writing a simple sentence to convey the same meaning instead of using a complex sentence.

I feel I don't have to use this sentence which is little complex because it has two parts which are combined using the conjunction 'and'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way (okay, it's only one way, but the sentence is too long for its content) to lose the conjunction is to lose the first verb:

> Mike inserts **a** small weapon into his jacket.

Maybe the word *pocket* should be added: *into his jacket **pocket***.

But this sentence requires some context that allows the reader to know that there are small weapons available for Mike to "take", e.g., prior sentences that say something like this:

> **Mike reviews his cache of killing instruments: knives, guns, grenades, cellphone-triggered C4 bombs, super-sized Big Macs, and New York City super-sized sodas. He carefully considers his target -- he's short and slim -- and his mission -- "Waste him!" was the way the Company had put it.** Mike inserts a small weapon into his jacket pocket....

Comment: Wow, your example is awesome. There is no other word that I can use instead of "put" or "insert"? Inserts doesn't seems to fit well in this context. I thought there will be some other better word.

Comment: @user43286: You missed the parenthetical disclaimer. But, of course, you can use a lot of other words, eg, _sticks, shoves, stuffs, slides, conceals, hides, jams, crams, stows, packs, places_. But your question was how to lose the conjunction. You didn't ask about replacing "inserts".

Comment: @user43286: My example is intended to be humorous as well as illustrative. I happy that you liked it. :-)

Comment: One thing to note is that several of the 'replacement words' for *put* or *insert* require the preposition to change from *into* to *in*; you don't "conceal a weapon into your jacket", for example.  (Also, a few more alternate verbs would be *slips*, *drops*, or *rams*.)

Comment: Personally, I would never use "insert" into a jacket/pocket. I would just use "put".

Answer (score 1):

> Mike puts the small weapon he took into [or inside] his jacket.

Also saying "Mike takes the small weapon and inserts it into his jacket" is not considered particularly complex, and both forms are acceptable. One note is that using two distinct clauses combined with the conjunction "and" can be more clear, as consider the following:

> Mike inserts the small weapon he took into his jacket.

Did Mike take a weapon and put it into his jacket, or did he "insert" the weapon that was in his jacket into something/someone else? We cannot tell from the sentence alone which is intended, and thus the use of two distinct clauses: the first clause notes the taking of a weapon, and the second clause notes what is done with the weapon that was taken.